# When dropped open textarea | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new with jQuery. All I want is to make sortable. When something is dropped, it hides and open textarea with save button. When the save button is clicked text from textarea writes to a paragraph.

I searched a lot and I found these fiddles:
[First one](http://jsfiddle.net/CxpMn/1/)
[Second one](http://jsfiddle.net/q5EXG/97/)

I want to 'merge' their functionality, but when I try it's not working. Here is my code:

```
$('#sortable').sortable().droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui){
        $(ui.draggable).html('<a id="send-thoughts" href="#">Click</a><textarea name="message"></textarea>');
    }
});
$('#draggables li').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#sortable',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    cursor: 'move'
});

$('#send-thoughts').click(function() 
{ var thought = $('textarea[name=message]').val();
  alert(thought);
});
```

Here is a fiddle with my work - jsfiddle.net/CxpMn/102/ (sorry, I need more reputation to post more links). Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

First, IDs cannot be duplicated in a page, so you need to use a class instead for `#send-thoughts`.

Second, you can't assign a click handler to elements that don't exist yet; so we need to delegate that event handler to an element that does exist, and target the future elements within it.

Third, we need to target the textarea that is related to the element clicked

```
$('#sortable').sortable().droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui){
        // use class instead of ID
        $(ui.draggable).html('<a class="send-thoughts" href="#">Click</a><textarea name="message"></textarea>');
    }
});

// delegate event to account for future elements
$(document).on('click','.send-thoughts',function() {
    // get the nearest textarea
   var thought = $(this).siblings('textarea[name=message]').val();
  alert(thought);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CxpMn/103/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are attaching a `click` handler to `#send-thoughts` before it is ever added to the DOM.  Try something like the following:

```
$('#sortable').sortable().droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui){
        $('#my-container').show();
    }
});
$('#draggables li').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '#sortable',
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    cursor: 'move'
});

$('#send-thoughts').click(function() 
{ var thought = $('textarea[name=message]').val();
  alert(thought);
});
```

In your HTML put:

```html
<div id="my-container" style="display: none">
    <a id="send-thoughts" href="">Click</a><textarea name="message"></textarea>
</div>
```